# Is it possible to use screen sketch in the monitor the taskbar is not?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10-v1607

I'm using Windows 10 (build 14393 Anniversary Update) and like to use **Windows Ink Workspace** by selecting **screen sketch**.

The problem I use two monitors and I like to use taskbar in just one. Looks like screen sketch is just activated in the screen taskbar is.

Is it possible to activate screen sketch in the other monitor?

**Edit**

Enable taskbar in both monitors is not an option since one of my screens is too little. I want a permanent solution and not a way to change my environment every time to make it possible.

Comment: Similar question about secondary display use: https://superuser.com/questions/1413773/how-to-use-microsoft-screen-sketch-on-multiple-monitors