# How to use Microsoft Screen Sketch on multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-10, snipping-tool

On Windows 10 build 17704, `Snipping Tool` includes a message from Microsoft asking or recommending users to switch to `Screen Sketch` app instead.

> Snipping Tool will be removed in a future update. Try improved
>   features and snip like usual with Screen Sketch

I have a two monitor setup, so pressing `Windows Logo + W` opens `Windows Ink Workspace`.

But the `Screen Sketch` only captures my primary display/monitor, how do I use it on my secondary display/monitor?

For now I'm using the `Windows Logo + Shift + S` feature, but this lacks the editing of the image since it stores the image to my clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

There are many programs that make taking a screen shot easy.

If you are working on an older device I would recommend LightShot. You simply press Print Screen button and it will instantly capture your screen. Then you can choose the area you want and edit it a bit and copy, save or upload the Image. [Lightshot Homepage](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html)

If you want more functions ShareX could also do the Job. It has a lot of effect and editing functions but I don't know exactly as I have never used it. [ShareX Homepage](https://getsharex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Open the "TASKBAR MANAGER".
Under Multiple display enable the Show taskbar on all displays (Put it to ON position).
In the "SHOW TASKBAR BUTTONS ON" select "Taskbar where window is open". Done!

Now you can choose where WINDOWS INK WORKSPACE under the taskbar Windows you want.

Hope this solution helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this does anything to solve the user's problem. Pressing Windows+W and choosing "Fullscreen snip" only screenshots the primary monitor, regardless of the setting that you mentioned, which I think is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing in Mar 2024, the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut unfortunately only captures the primary monitor. There is a workaround, however.

If you click the "Windows Ink Workspace" icon in the taskbar *on the secondary monitor* then it will popup a similar window.

[image: Windows Ink Workspace Fullscreen snip button]

When you click "Fullscreen snip" it will screenshot just that monitor from where you activated it.

If you're not seeing this icon in your taskbar, right-click on the clock in your taskbar and choose "Show Windows Ink Workspace button".